# matrices and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and  $G={}^{t\!}AA$

We assume that $\operatorname{rk}(A)=p$

To show that $\det(G)>0$ the argument provided is $\det G=(\det A)^2>0$, unfortunately I don't understand, because for me  this argument holds only if $A\in \mathcal{M}_{p}(\mathbb{R})$ (a square matrix)

Comment: $G$ doesn't make sense... I'm not familiar with putting the transpose on the left of the matrix.  Do you mean $G=A^tA$?  Also how do you know that $\det(A)\neq 0$?  Finally, what is your question?

Comment: What is $rg(A)$?

Comment: sorry but $$rg(A)=p$$

Comment: Google "Cauchy-Binet identity".

Comment: Probably the rank (in French). @Squirtle: `t` as a prescript to denote the transpose is Bourbaki's notation.

Comment: exactly that is the rank

Comment: @Stu The statement is false, unless you assume $n\le p$. For $n>p$, the matrix $G$ is not invertible, so its determinant is $0$. If the rank of $A$ is $p$ and $n\le p$, then $G$ is indeed invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression $(\det A)^2$ indeed doesn't make sense because $A$ is not necessarily square. As pointed out in a comment, you may use Cauchy-Binet formula to prove the statement. Alternatively, as $A$ has full column rank, if $x\in\mathbb R^p$ is nonzero, then $Ax\ne0$ and $x^TGx=x^TA^TAx=\|Ax\|^2>0$. Therefore $G$ is symmetric positive definite and it has a positive determinant.